# PHP redirect user on multiple pages

Tags: javascript, php, redirect

I'm building an admin site for work and it's my first PHP project. I've been able to get the login page to work and when signed in it will take you to either the Sales, admin or director page.

```php
if (count($errors) == 0) {
    $password = md5($password);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password' LIMIT 1";
    $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) { // user found
        // check if user is admin or user
        $logged_in_user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);
        if ($logged_in_user['user_type'] == 'admin') {

            $_SESSION['user'] = $logged_in_user;
            $_SESSION['success']  = "You are now logged in";
            header('location: dashboard/admin.php');          
        }elseif ($logged_in_user['user_type'] == 'director') {

            $_SESSION['user'] = $logged_in_user;
            $_SESSION['success']  = "You are now logged in";

            header('location: dashboard/director.php');
        }elseif($logged_in_user['user_type'] == 'user'){
            $_SESSION['user'] = $logged_in_user;
            $_SESSION['success']  = "You are now logged in";

            header('location: dashboard/sales.php');
        }
    }else {
        array_push($errors, "Wrong username/password combination");
    }
}
```

The problem I have is all 3 user types will be using 3 of the same pages. For example, one page will be to create a customer. When they have entered this information it will take them to a page to say successful or what errors there are. When they press the home button or Logo I want to take them back to there dashboard. So, if you are signed in as sales go back to sales dashboard.

```
<a href="home.php">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="../files/assets/images/logo.png" alt="Theme-Logo">
</a>
```

I'm not sure how to do this. I was thinking to send them to a page (i.e. home) and that page redirects them to the correct dashboard. Is this right or is there a better way to get round this?

Comment: You are indeed saying it correctly, redirect them to a main page, where you decide based on the session key, which page will be displayed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your homepage, or dashboard page you could do something like the following:

```
<?php

function get_user_type()
{
// Your implementation here.
}
switch(get_user_type()) {
    case 'director':
        include 'director_dashboard.php';
        break;
    // and so on
    default:
        include 'not_logged_in_dashboard.php';
}
```

Comment: Or swap the includes for redirects.  Just beware of redirect loops.  Redirects can be a minor irritation, due to double fetches for a page.